# Select several columns but only rows with Max Value on a Column and join with different databases

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, uniqueidentifier

I got a problem with a SQL query that I can't seem to solve.

I have a table with orders, the **order number** is **unique** in the first table, which looks like this:

```
+-------+------------+
| Order | Orderdate  |
+-------+------------+
| 10122 | 19.03.2013 |
| 10123 | 15.03.2013 |
| 10124 | 19.03.2013 |
| 10125 | 17.03.2013 |
| 10126 | 07.03.2013 |
| 10127 | 01.03.2013 |
| 10128 | 16.03.2013 |
| 10129 | 10.03.2013 |
| 10130 | 22.03.2013 |
+-------+------------+
```

The second table has status updates for the order:

```
+---------+----------------+--------------+------------+
|  Order  |  Statuschange  |  Changedate  | Changetype |
+---------+----------------+--------------+------------+
|   10127 |             12 |              | Admin      |
|   10127 |              3 |  04.03.2013  | Packaging  |
|   10127 |              4 |  10.03.2013  | Shipping   |
|   10127 |              5 |  13.03.2013  | Packaging  |
|   10127 |              5 |  15.03.2013  | Shipping   |
|   10127 |              6 |  19.03.2013  | Admin      |
|   10127 |              7 |  24.03.2013  | Shipping   |
|   10127 |              8 |  25.03.2013  | Admin      |
|   10127 |              8 |  26.03.2013  | Packaging  |
|   10127 |              8 |  27.03.2013  | Admin      |
|   10127 |              8 |  29.03.2013  | Shipping   |
|   10127 |              8 |  30.03.2013  | Shipping   |
|   10127 |             12 |  01.07.2013  | Shipping   |
|   10127 |              8 |  02.07.2013  | Shipping   |
+---------+----------------+--------------+------------+
```

From that table, I want to get the row that has the highest number in statuschange and if there are several of them then the one with the highest date.
I also want the results of this to be restricted to one Changetype, e.g. Shipping.

The problem is the second table does not have a unique identifier.

My final query output should look like this:

```
+-------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| Order | Orderdate  | Statuschange | Changedate | Changetype |
+-------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| 10127 | 01.03.2013 |           12 | 01.07.2013 |  Shipping  |
+-------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

Thus far I've only been able to get the highest status change but not both the date of the change and the status number of the change.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: sql server or mysql , which dbms ?

Comment: sql and I think the dbms is Microsoft, not sure which year though

Comment: @Spurious You mean SQL Server? Then you should tag your question accordingly. (SQL is a language, not a product, and it has several dialects, hence the questions for the product.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DBMS supports `WITH` clauses and window functions, you can use

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT o.Order,
       o.Orderdate,
       s.Statuschange,
       s.Changedate,
       s.Changetype,
       Row_number() OVER(partition by o.Order
                         order by s.statuschange desc, s.changedate desc)
                 as no
  FROM Orders o
       JOIN Statuschange s ON o.Order = s.Order
 WHERE s.Changetype = 'Shipping'
)
SELECT Order,
       Orderdate,
       Statuschange,
       Changedate,
       Changetype
  FROM a
 WHERE no = 1
```

`Row_number() over(...)` does the main work here: it first partitions the result set into partitions, where all records having the same value of `o.Order` get to the same partition. Then, within each partition, it numbers the records starting from 1, ordered first by `s.statuschange` descending, and those with the same `s.statuschange` value by `s.changedate` descending.

Finally, the outer select just excludes all the records not having number `1` via is `WHERE` clause, which effectively returns the records with the maximum `changedate` of those having the maximum `statuschange` for each `Order`.

This assumes the following - which is not absolutely clear from your question:

- You want to have the entry with the maximum `changedate` of those having the maximum `statuschange` **per order**. (Reading your question literally, you request the entry with the maximum `changedate` of those having the maximum `statuschange` **across all orders**. If that would really be your request, you should omit the `partition by o.Order`.)
- You want to see the `Changetype` in the result (which you did not state, your expected result does not contain this column).

Comment: I get a wrong syntax near "(" line 6 error for this solution.

Comment: @Spurious Is line 6 where `Row_number()` is? Then, maybe your DBMS does not support that function. SQL Server does from 2005, and many other DMBSs do as well.

Comment: No, actually there needs to be a comma after `s.Changedate`, that seems to be all.

Comment: Is there a way to include a condition in there?
There is another field in the status changes table. The field is customer type and it includes premium, regular, professional, amateur amongst others and I want to only get the results for e.g. premium.

Comment: @Spurious Probably yes. Where do you want to include which condition?

Comment: The condition for the row_numbers should be:
highest status, latest date and customertype = 'premium'
I was thinking of an IF clause but not sure if feasible.

Comment: To clarify further, the customertype would be in the statuschange table not the order table.

Comment: @Spurious Does the customer type change due to a status change? And if so, is the type of the last changedate of the highest statuschange the type to return? Then just add it to both selection lists. Or are only status changes with certain customer types relevant, and only statuschanges involving these types should be used? Without a clear detailed requirement, it is difficult to even guess an answer.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I amended my OP. I changed the example values to something that makes more sense. I now want to only get the values where the Changetype is shipping.

Comment: `You do not want to have any condition to restrict e. g. the entries of the Statuschange table on only some types of column Changetype.`

I think that is pretty much what I want. I only want to have the highest status number and the highest date for the rows with a certain changetype. I dont want/need to see the changetype in the final result.

Comment: I extended my OP with the comments.

Comment: @Spurious I edited my answer again, adding a new `WHERE` condition with the `ChangeType` as requested, and removing my wrong assumption. Actually, I would have preferred to give that answer initially. Maybe next time you can state your requirements a bit more precise in the question from the beginning?

Comment: I wasn't aware of those requirements in the beginning. They came up along the way. I appreciate the effort you've put into this. Thank you! One follow up question, what if the row number 1 is a different change type? Will the event then be omitted? Do we need to amend `partition by o.Order` by another criteria?

Comment: Just checked it, not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH ff AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Order ORDER BY Statuschange DESC, Changedate DESC) num, *
    FROM [second table]
)
    SELECT f.Order, f.Orderdate, s.Statuschange, s.Changedate  
    FROM [first table] f
    LEFT JOIN  ff s on f.Order = s.Order AND s.num > 1
```